# Is there any difference between fadeIn() and show() based on their performance?

Tags: jquery, performance

I would like to know is there any difference in performance between `fadeIn` and `show`.
People keep suggesting me to use `show` rather than `fadeIn`.I researched through lot of websites but all turned out to be diplomatic answers. Looking for more specific and performance oriented solution.

Comment: There is a performance difference, but there are many factors to it that you can't just calculate the difference, different browsers will have different performance stats, most modern computers and browsers won't notice much difference, but people on old laptops or lower performing systems will notice more lag using `fadeIn` especially when using older browsers (like IE8 or below kind of age)

Comment: Fadein is a method which animates opacity so performance is lesser compared to show()..
U can even time the show funtion refer API for more info..
http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/

Comment: Performance? What that means here? A animation will always take more resource than changing a simple CSS rule. But show() can be used to animate too, so...

Comment: Even with `fadeIn(0)`, the performance is noticeably worse than `show()`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`show` simply changes the `display` property to `block`(it can be other values depends on the previous value).

`fadeIn` increases the opacity value every couple of milliseconds  until the value `1.0` which is obviously a lot more expensive,

Regarding to the which is better, none is better! They do two different things!
If you simply need to show something hidden use `show`.
If you need to animate something hidden to fade in use `fadeIn`

Comment: @A.Wolff, that's true, they added an overload with a `duration` parameter, I have no idea why they did that.